# URL with German character(ä) getting changed to unknown format when requesting in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I am requesting a HTTP GET web service from angular having parameters with German character

URL : http://example.com/services/download/?key=123&fileName=**längenmasse.png**

With following function

```js
public downloadFile(fileName: string) {
    window.open("http://example.com/services/download/?key=" + this.key + "&fileName=" + fileName);
}
```

It is converting to the following url

http://example.com/services/download/?key=123&fileName=l%E4ngenmasse.png

because of this I'm getting a error message from services as the fileName parameter value has changed.

Comment: Did you try  encoding  the url ? with URL encoder, it could works  
 [link](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is not with angular, but actually with how the window.open function is encoding your uri.

You could try to open your new window and provide the new location separately as it does not encode it for you, and then you can encode the individual parts as needed.

```
public downloadFile(fileName: string) {
    var win = window.open();
    win.location = "http://example.com/services/download/?key=" + this.key + "&fileName=" + fileName;
    win.focus();
}
```